# How do I set up Pear mail?

Tags: php, email, smtp, pear

I'm trying to set up php mail with pear. I've been trying and researching for the past 4 hours  without success.

I'm using this code

```
<?php
 require_once "Mail.php";

 $from = "Sandra Sender <sender@example.com>";
 $to = "Ramona Recipient <recipient@example.com>";
 $subject = "Hi!";
 $body = "Hi,\n\nHow are you?";

 $host = "ssl://mail.example.com";
 $port = "465";
 $username = "smtp_username";
 $password = "smtp_password";

 $headers = array ('From' => $from,
   'To' => $to,
   'Subject' => $subject);
 $smtp = Mail::factory('smtp',
   array ('host' => $host,
     'port' => $port,
     'auth' => true,
     'username' => $username,
     'password' => $password));

 $mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $body);

 if (PEAR::isError($mail)) {
   echo("<p>" . $mail->getMessage() . "</p>");
  } else {
   echo("<p>Message successfully sent!</p>");
  }
 ?>
```

And the 'require_once "Mail.php"' is giving this error:

**Warning: require_once(Mail.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/creatif2/public_html/mail.php on line 3
Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required 'Mail.php' (include_path='.:php/') in /home/creatif2/public_html/mail.php on line 3**

Pear and Pear Mail is installed

**Auth_SASL 1.0.6   Update Reinstall Uninstall Show Docs
Mail    1.2.0   Update Reinstall Uninstall Show Docs
Net_SMTP    1.6.1   Update Reinstall Uninstall Show Docs
Net_Socket  1.0.10  Update Reinstall Uninstall Show Docs**

And I'm quite baffled about it. I think my problem is setting the include path but I'm not getting anywhere with it.

The packages **are** located within the php folder - (eg home/my_user/php/Mail.php, I'm using Justhost).

The current configuration is
**.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php**

Can someone please explain to me how to reference the Mail.php file properly? Been stuck here the whole morning and afternoon.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you are not using the correct path in the include. Assuming your include path starts in the document root, you should use:

```
require_once "/home/my_user/php/Mail.php";
```

Although it might take you some testing to find the correct path for the require

Comment: How do I find the correct path? I've referenced it through $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/../php" which should be right and I get this error: Warning: require_once(PEAR.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/creatif2/php/Mail.php on line 46

Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required 'PEAR.php' (include_path='/home/creatif2/public_html/../php') in /home/creatif2/php/Mail.php on line 46

Comment: The problem is that Mail.php is opened correctly, but inside Mail.php there is a call to PEAR.php, that doesn't get included correctly. You should add `/home/creatif2/php/` to your include path with *set_include_path();*

Comment: I added the set_include_path, but I still get **Warning: require_once(PEAR.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/creatif2/php/Mail.php on line 46**. In fact, I cannot find PEAR.php myself anywhere - where should it be located?

Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required 'PEAR.php' (include_path='/home/creatif2/php/') in /home/creatif2/php/Mail.php on line 46

Comment: PEAR.php should be in the same directory as Mail.php (/home/creatif2/php/) . Try removing the last `/` of the include path. I'm not sure what's making it fail

Comment: Contacted my web host and it was just a problem with their servers! Anyways, it should be fixed soon. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when trying to send email. You have to install the Pear Mail package with all the dependencies, I couldnt install until reinstall reinstalled the the PEAR Package Manager see http://pear.php.net/manual/en/installation.getting.php I'm sure this will help

Comment: I just went through this whole thing as well. On my host, PEAR package manager was installed, but PEAR itself wasn't! So I had to install PEAR and Mail for the script to work.